# Items not imported to CRUD database app, and can't retrieve values

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a simple app, the HTML is simple:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="create.php"><strong>Create</strong></a> - add a food by 
 name</li>
<li><a href="read.php"><strong>Read</strong></a> - find a food and the 
nutrition values</li>
    <li><a href="update.php"><strong>Create</strong></a> - update a foods 
values</li>
<li><a href="delete.php"><strong>Read</strong></a> - delete an entry</li>
</ul>
```

I have one database named "test" and successfully created the table "foodnames", this is evident in the mySQL admin, so I won't post the sql init file.

When I try to add an item(food), i get the following error message:

> INSERT INTO foodnames (foodName, calories, proteins, carbohydrates,
>   fats) values (:foodName, :calories, :proteins, :carbohydrates, :fats)
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'food.foodnames' doesn't exist

Here is my create.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

require "../config.php";
require "../common.php";
try 
{
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $new_food = array(
        "foodName" => $_POST['foodName'],
        "calories"  => $_POST['calories'],
        "proteins"     => $_POST['proteins'],
        "carbohydrates"       => $_POST['carbohydrates'],
        "fats"  => $_POST['fats']
    );
    $sql = sprintf(
            "INSERT INTO %s (%s) values (%s)",
            "foodnames",
            implode(", ", array_keys($new_food)),
            ":" . implode(", :", array_keys($new_food))
    );

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute($new_food);
 }
 catch(PDOException $error) 
 {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
 }

  }
 ?>

 <?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

 <?php 
 if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $statement) 
 { ?>
<blockquote><?php echo $_POST['foodName']; ?> successfully added.
</blockquote>
<?php 
 } ?>

 <h2>Add a food</h2>

 <form method="post">
<label for="foodName">Foods Name</label>
<input type="text" name="foodName" id="foodName">
<label for="calories">Calories per 100 grams</label>
<input type="text" name="calories" id="calories">
<label for="proteins">Proteins in %</label>
<input type="text" name="proteins" id="proteins">
<label for="carbohydrates">Carbohydrates in %</label>
<input type="text" name="carbohydrates" id="carbohydrates">
<label for="fats">Fats in %</label>
<input type="text" name="fats" id="fats">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<a href="index.php">Back to home</a>

<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Why is this looking for food.foodnames? Instead of test.foodnames and what would be the proper syntax? As previously stated, there is only one test database(food db does not exist) and the table foodnames is there.

Further, when I try to read from the database, I get the following error

> Notice: Undefined index: userInput in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\read.php
>   on line 19 SELECT * FROM foodnames WHERE FoodName LIKE :user_input
>   SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\read.php
>   on line 37 No results found for  Notice: Undefined index: location in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\public\read.php on line 74

What I am trying there is to retrieve a database entry based on user input, even if he only inputs one character, here ist the read.php code:

```
<?php
/**
* Function to query information based on 
* a parameter: in this case, food name.
*
*/
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

try 
{

    require "../config.php";
    require "../common.php";
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $sql = "SELECT * 
                    FROM foodnames
                    WHERE FoodName LIKE :user_input";
    $userInput = $_POST['userInput'] . '%';
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':FoodName', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
}

catch(PDOException $error) 
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
}
}
?>
<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

<?php  
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
if ($result && $statement->rowCount() > 0) 
{ ?>
    <h2>Results</h2>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Food Name</th>
                <th>Calories/100g</th>
                <th>Proteins</th>
                <th>Carbohydrates</th>
                <th>Fats</th>
                <th>Time to burn by running</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
  <?php 
    foreach ($result as $row) 
    { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo escape($row["id"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo escape($row["foodNAme"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo escape($row["calories"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo escape($row["proteins"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo escape($row["carbohydrates"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo escape($row["fats"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo escape($row["ttb"]); ?> </td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    } ?>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 <?php 
 } 
 else 
  { ?>
    <blockquote>No results found for <?php echo escape($_POST['location']); 
 ?>.</blockquote>
<?php
} 
 }?> 

<h2>Find food by name</h2>




<form method="post">
<label for="food">Food</label>
<input type="text" id="food" name="food">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Results">
</form>

<a href="index.php">Back to home</a>

<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Sorry for the very verbose code.

Comment: '...WHERE FoodName LIKE : FoodName' and not user_input, you'll need to use the parameter name, not the php variable.

Comment: And in vase of the insert you are probably connecting to the wrong database on the server.

Comment: Have a look at your config, I bet it's food and not test there.

Comment: @axel.michel
Hm, I just notice, if I have to use foodName, then I have no reference in the form. So this:
WHERE FoodName LIKE :user_input";
    $userInput = $_POST['userInput'] . '%';

and this
<form method="post">
<label for="food">Food</label>
<input type="text" id="food" name="food">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Results">
</form>
Need changes. How do I go on about this?

Comment: @ptts The name attribut of input field is the key in the $_POST array. So if your input field has the name food, you'll do it like: $userInput = $_POST['food']

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the config file. You need to change the database to test database i.e. $db   = 'test';  //Change database from food

Comment: LOL, this is embarassing:-) This is my very first db project, it was a nightmare including all the server configuration quirks, but now it works:-)
Well, the read part does not work yet, but thanks